# Selenium get last browser window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Every time I run my test selenium opens another Firefox window. It's annoying to see so many windows after several runs of the test. Is it possible to utilize the previous opened one?

Comment: You can reuse your browser if you introduce Singleton pattern http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/7015/6194

Comment: I already know that and it does not address my issue. Suppose I have a Selenium instance closed in the last run without quiting the Firefox. I need to reuse the previously opened Firefox since the loading time of Selenium is quite consuming.

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium 2 (WebDriver), try creating a new object for FF:

```
ffWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This should create an object of the Firefox web-driver that you can control and won't be quit until you call:

```
ffWebDriver.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something NOT possible. Please look into https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18 to have an idea why is it so. If only multiple windows opened is a problem here, you can quit all the browser instances opened after each test by calling `driver.quit();` method.

In case you are using Python bindings, you might want to have a look into this : http://webdriverplus.org/en/latest/browsers.html#reuse-browser

Comment: How to close just the Selenium's Firefox instances only using C# or VB.NET. Finding Processes by 'Firefox' name would returns all the Firefox windows. Killing them may also close the unwanted Firefox windows.

Comment: For C# please use `driver.Quit()`. This will ONLY close browser instances opened by Selenium. Manually opened instances will be opened as they are.